# dynamically create a cascading delegate

Tags: c#, .net

I want to write a series of delegates that call one another.  It's a bit like a multicast delegate, but not so -- it's "serial" a serial need.  Internal logic in each delegate says that each subsequent call must come from the prior delegate and not from a marshalling mechanism.

**Example**:

```
    [Test]
    public void Test2() {
        Action a = () => {
            Action b = () => {
                Action c = () => {
                    Console.WriteLine("test");
                };
                c.Invoke();
            };
            b.Invoke();
        };
        a.Invoke();
    }
```

This looks possible via codegen, but I'd rather not do it that way.

Any ideas?

Comment: ... May I ask why this is useful?

Comment: What part of it are you dynamically generating?  Generating from what source?

Comment: Delegates are not for this requirement. Each call does not depenet on previous calls output unless there is a failure (exception). You need to implement a Chain of responsiblity pattern for your req i guess.

Comment: @Mehrdad: A) why is it useful?  Think about another way to express a recursive function.  Compilers sometimes unwind recursion to be flat loops.  In this case, it's more natural/flexible to think in terms of delgates.  It makes more sense in terms of asynchronous cases + try / catch / finally + locking + etc.  i.e. we'd like discrete, provable components, and not a harder to understand/ debug / maintain recursive definition.  The visitor take a path through a tree, and then retrace its steps.  Simple on the surface.  Not so in practice.  It's a preference.

Comment: @mellamokb: I had a loop, and calls between delegates were getting wrapped through a passed in variable.  I think the "by reference" aspect of delegates was bringing this unstuck.  Not sure yet.

Comment: @sgtz: Oh I see. So you need a sequential-to-continuation-passing-style transformer?

Comment: @zenwalker: chain of responsibility might work, however the answer would be far more verbose + I have reservations (slower, more error prone, more mermory intensive, more verbose)

Comment: I don't know of a way you can do it with plain delegates, but you could do this easily enough with tasks and continuations. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537612.aspx

Comment: Are you looking for [`async`/ `await`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @dtb: I explored async and await via the CTP a while back.  So no.  Async / await is not the best fit for this need.

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what you're trying to achieve? Currently it seems your example can be shortened to `public void Test2() { Console.WriteLine("test"); }` without any difference in the outcome.

Comment: @JimMischel: continuations are soo close.  Would like to initiate the continuation from within the body of the first task though.

Comment: Any chance you are looking for [y-combinator in C#](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wesdyer/archive/2007/02/02/anonymous-recursion-in-c.aspx)? May not be exactly what you want but shows a way to create recursive function...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: this might be what I'm looking for.  Thanks.  I'll dig into some more.  Hmmm (just scanning the post)... I would still prefer to get the delegate based idea going.  I'll try this out though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a linked list of delegates? Something like this:

```
public class Node
{
    protected Node Next { get; private set; }

    private Delegate m_actionDel;
    private object[] m_args;

    public Node(Node next, Delegate actionToPerform)
    {
        Next = next;
        m_actionDel = actionToPerform;
    }        

    public void InvokeChain()
    {
        try
        {
            m_actionDel.DynamicInvoke(m_args);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            // handle exception
        }

        if (Next != null)
            Next.InvokeChain();
    }
}
```

This is just a quick draft, I haven't actually compiled or run this code, but it should give you an idea.